# PHP: Combine these two SQL queries into one

Tags: php, mysql, database, mariadb

I use MariaDB and have a table where each row has a date and a score.

I want to first show the rows where the date is 3 days old or newer, sorted by the score - then show the rest (more than 3 days old) sorted by date.

Since my date is stored in unix time, it's fairly easy to have php calculate 3 days from before now and use that as my $scoreTimeLimit variable in the below:

Here are my two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myDate > $scoreTimeLimit ORDER BY myPopularityScore DESC

SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myDate < $scoreTimeLimit ORDER BY myDate DESC
```

However, I would VERY much like to have only 1 query instead of two. Can it be done...?

Comment: `UNION` perhaps? Or just one query with a `CASE` for your `ORDER BY`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job for UNION.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 0 ord1, NOW() as ord2, * 
    FROM myTable WHERE myDate > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 ord1, myDate as ord2, * 
    FROM myTable WHERE myDate <= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY
) a 
ORDER BY ord1, ord2 DESC, myPopularityScore
```

The inner query gives you a single result set with a couple of extra columns added on to help you manage your sorting.

Comment: Thanks O. Jones -- your answer was key to my final result. As such, the syntax wasn't compatible with my mysqli/mariadb or whatever - I kept getting errors.

But using the principle you presented, I ended up with a working version which looks like this:

(
SELECT *, 0 AS mainsort, timeline_popularity AS testsort
FROM site_timeline 
WHERE timeline_timestamp >= $popularTimeLimit
) 

UNION ALL

(
SELECT *, 1 AS mainsort, timeline_timestamp AS testsort
FROM site_timeline 
WHERE timeline_timestamp < $popularTimeLimit
) 

ORDER BY mainsort ASC, testsort DESC

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out why stackoverflow doesn't display my line breaks - so my above answer looks very messy... but thanks for the help - you qued my in on exactly what I needed.